# Angularjs $resource POST sends more than I want

Tags: spring, angularjs

This is my factory

```
    .factory('UsersFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8080/user?deep=:deep', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {deep: '@deep'}, isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/create' },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/delete/:pk', params: { pk: '@pk' } },
        save: {
            method: 'POST', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/update',
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                return '';
            },
            transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter) {
                return '';
            },
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}])
```

In my controller I have this method

```
UsersFactory.save(user);
```

My issue is that the resource post method is wrapping my users data like this

```
{
"data": "",
"status": 0,
"config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/update",
    "data": {
        "pk": 4,
        "created": 1404293276408,
        "lastModified": 1404293276408,
        "dataVersion": 1,
        "username": "helm",
        "firstName": "Matthew",
        "lastName": "Hel",
        "email": "",
        "mobile": "",
        "roles": [
            {
                "created": "",
                "dataVersion": "",
                "description": "",
                "fullName": "Super User",
                "lastModified": "",
                "pk": "",
                "shortName": "SU",
                "type": "su"
            },
            {
                "created": "",
                "dataVersion": "",
                "description": "",
                "fullName": "Administrator",
                "lastModified": "",
                "pk": "",
                "shortName": "Admin",
                "type": "admin"
            }
        ],
        "roleTypes": [
            "su",
            "admin"
        ]
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
},
"statusText": ""
```

}

My server can't handle this structure.. How do I on send the body i.e. user object only? Or do I need to change my Spring bean? Or is there some configurations that I need to do on Angularjs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's why I switched from $resource to restangular

Comment: Thanks I'll look into restangular.. Its been driving me crazy.

Comment: STEVER I'm still getting the same problem with restangular. Do you have an example?

Comment: it's definitely something wrong with your $http provider configuration. Have you removed resource at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, specifying `transformRequest/Response` as functions that return `''` beats the whole purpose.

That left aside, it **[seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Pvjj7/)**.

Maybe the error is somewhere else...